# How to make async/await wait for an Observable to return

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, rxjs, observable

Fairly new to Angular, and struggling with Promises, Observables and async/await.

- I have a function which needs the current user details to do some tasks.
- For this, I wrote a fetch user detail method which returns a promise and the tasks are handled within the 'then' part.
- The fetch method itself calls another method which invokes the http.get to get the user details from database, and returns an Observable.
- I used async/await here for the function to wait for http.get to return.

However, this doesn't seem to work. I have a feeling this has something to do with how Observables/subscribe works, but I am unable to solve it.

Code snippet:

```js
    initPage() {
      fetchCurrentUserDetails().then((user) => { //tasks dependent on current user
        //task 1
        //task 2
      });
    }

    fetchCurrentUserDetails(): Promise<any> {
      return Promise.resolve((async () => {
        let currentUser = this.global.getUser();// check if user is defined already
        let userId: string = sessionStorage.getItem('userid');

        if (currentUser == undefined) {
          let initProfile = new Promise(resolve => resolve(this.fetchDetailsFromDB(userId)));
          const profile: any = await initProfile; //Waits, but returns before the Observable comes back

          let user = new User();
          // initialize user with the fetched values
          user.id = profile.id; // Undefined, since value not returned yet
          user.name = profile.user_name; // Undefined, since value not returned yet
          // Set this user in a global variable
          this.global.setUser(user);
       }

       return this.global.getUser();
      })());
    }

    fetchDetailsFromDB(userId: string) {
      //callProfileService has nothing but the http.get statement
      this.callProfileService(userId).subscribe((response) => {
        let profile = response.body.response.data.user;
         return profile;
      });
    }
```

Edit: adding how I tried with toPromise:

```js
    fetchDetailsFromDB(userId: string) {
      this.callUserProfileService(userId).toPromise().then((response) => {
       let profile = response.body.response.data.user;
       return profile;
    });
```

Is this the right way to do this? If so, how to make the await wait for the Observable to return?

Comment: Observables have a `toPromise()` function on them...

Comment: Did you consider using [`toPromise`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) ?

Comment: Yes, I tried a toPromise as well, but the values were still undefined, and did not wait for the observable to finish. I have edited the question with that snippet as well.

Comment: you forgot to return the promise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, you need the `toPromise()` method, but don't forget to *return* that promise (the `return` in  the callback is not enough -- the function `fetchDetailsFromDB` needs to *return* a promise).

On the rest of your code: it is an antipattern to use `Promise.resolve` and `new Promise` like that: as a rule of thumb, don't create a new promise with either of these when you already have a promise to work with (e.g. from an API function call).

So here is how you could do it with `async` methods:

```
async fetchCurrentUserDetails(): Promise<any> {
//^^^^
    let currentUser = this.global.getUser();
    if (currentUser == undefined) {
      const userId: string = sessionStorage.getItem('userid');
      const profile: any = await this.fetchDetailsFromDB(userId);
      currentUser = new User();
      currentUser.id = profile.id;
      currentUser.name = profile.user_name;
      this.global.setUser(currentUser);
   }
   return currentUser;
}

async fetchDetailsFromDB(userId: string): Promise<any> {
   const response = await this.callUserProfileService(userId).toPromise();
   return response.body.response.data.user;
};
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you! For pointing out how to return the promise as well as educating about the anti-pattern.

Comment: It works but fail when test. Next to the await, the function with .toPromise() says "its not a function", but only on testing environment. ¿How do you test it?

Comment: I cannot really help without seeing your definition of `callUserProfileService`. Since you referenced it in your code as a function, I assumed it was. Another problem can be that you call `fetchDetailsFromDB` not as a method from your class instance, but pass around this function as a callback. If you do that, `this` will not be as expected, and then `this.callUserProfileService` will not exist.

Comment: Well, its because my sut needs an instance. I had sut = new sut(mockedService), but it needs: sut = new sut(instance(mockedService)). When you mock(anyClass), ts-mockito didn't returns an instance. It's an important topic if you are used to Java mockito, for example.

Comment: I think this deserves a new question, as it is likely related to how you test, and in particular how you communicate the method `fetchDetailsFromDB` to the test framework. I'm quite sure it means `this` is not defined. You could debug and show the value of `this` just before the call to `this.callUserProfileService` and you'll see it is undefined or the global object, but not your instance object.

Answer (score 2):

you can use callback

```
initPage() {
    fetchCurrentUserDetails((user) => {
        //task 1
        //task 2
    });
}

fetchCurrentUserDetails(callback) {
    const currentUser = this.global.getUser();

    if (!currentUser) {
        const userId: string = sessionStorage.getItem('userid');
        return this.callProfileService(userId).subscribe((response) => {
            const profile = response.body.response.data.user;
            let user = new User();
            user.id = profile.id;
            user.name = profile.user_name;
            this.global.setUser(user);
            return callback(user);
        });
    } else {
        return callback(currentUser);
    }
}
```