# How to test await toPromise() inside async function? (.toPromise() is not a function error)

Tags: typescript, angular6, karma-jasmine, ts-mockito

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58720321/how-to-make-async-await-wait-for-an-observable-to-return), I wrote this test:

```
it('call service when search product by code', async() => {
    let code: string = 'CODE';
    let product: Product = createProduct();
    let properties: ProductProperties = createProductProperties();
    when(mockProductService.getProductByCode(code)).thenReturn(of(product));
    when(mockProductService.getProductProperties(product.id)).thenReturn(of(properties));

    let result: Product = await sut.searchProductByCode(code);

    expect(result.code).toEqual(product.code);
    expect(result.properties).toEqual(properties);
    verify(mockProductService.getProductByCode(code));
    verify(mockProductService.getProductProperties(product.id));
  });
```

The function I'm testing is:

```
async searchProductByCode(code: string): Promise<Product> {
    let product = await this.productService.getProductByCode(code).toPromise(); //fails running test
    product.properties = await this.productService.getProductProperties(product.id).toPromise();
    return product;
  }
```

The function runs OK but the test fails:

> TypeError: this.productService.getProductByCode(...).toPromise is not a function

Is like I'm not correctly mocking the service?

The method productService.getProductByCode() returns an Observable of Product:

```
getProductByCode(code: string): Observable<Product>
```

The method of(product) creates an Observable object of product. And method .toPromise() is a method from Observable, that returns a promise from the observable. Here the import:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: of(product) return an Observable of product. toPromise() is a method of Observable that returns a promise from the observable. I edited to enlarge the info about my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, changing my keywords to search about it, I've got [a good answer](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito/issues/164). I was mocking my service badly.

This (my code) is wrong:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    mockProductService = mock(ProductService);
    mockStationService = mock(StationService);

    sut = new QuickStationChangeComponentService(
      mockProductService,
      mockStationService,
    );
  });
```

To make it works, it needs an instance:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    mockProductService = mock(ProductService);
    mockStationService = mock(StationService);

    sut = new QuickStationChangeComponentService(
      instance(mockProductService),
      instance(mockStationService),
    );
  });
```

I was focusing on a wrong way to approach it to search.

If you, like me, are used to Java and think that mock(class) returns a mocked instance of class, you are wrong. If you want an instance like in my tests, you need to create an instance of mock.